# String[] from post to Dictionary or Hashtable in C# .net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net

I have a post that has an array of items coming in that have no int for keys but a string for a key.  for example: (from post)

```
-----------------------------3805226668837
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pool[Abelson_2834.jpg]"

general_pool
-----------------------------3805226668837
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pool_place[Abelson_2834.jpg]"

1
-----------------------------3805226668837
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mediatype[Abelson_2834.jpg]"

3
-----------------------------3805226668837
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pool[Abelson_2852.jpg]"

general_pool
-----------------------------3805226668837
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pool_place[Abelson_2852.jpg]"

1
-----------------------------3805226668837
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mediatype[Abelson_2852.jpg]"

3
-----------------------------3805226668837
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pool[Abelson_3160-1.jpg]"

general_pool
-----------------------------3805226668837
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pool_place[Abelson_3160-1.jpg]"

1
-----------------------------3805226668837
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mediatype[Abelson_3160-1.jpg]"

3
-----------------------------3805226668837
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="Abelson_2834.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

So "pool" is an array with the keys set as the name and it's value is set aa a string.

from the form that lookes like this basicly

```
<tbody data-target="#modal-gallery" data-toggle="modal-gallery" class="files">
  <tr class="template-upload fade in">
    <td class="preview"><span class="fade in">
      <canvas width="80" height="54"></canvas>
      </span></td>
    <td class="name"><span>Abelson_2834.jpg</span></td>
    <td class="size"><span>4.17 MB</span></td>
    <td><div aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" role="progressbar" class="progress progress-success progress-striped active">
        <div style="width:0%;" class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div="forminputs"> <span style="display:inline-block;float:left;">Choose a pool:
      <select style="display:inline-block;" name="pool[Abelson_2834.jpg]">
        <option selected="selected" value="general_pool">General</option>
        <option value="place">Places</option>
        <option value="geo">Geometrics</option>
        <option value="ads">Advertisment</option>
      </select>
      <span class="pool_place"> <br>
      Choose a pool:
      <select style="display:inline-block;" name="pool_place[Abelson_2834.jpg]">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">place 1</option>
        <option value="2">Places</option>
        <option value="3">Geometrics</option>
        <option value="4">Advertisment</option>
      </select>
      </span> </span> <span style="display:inline-block;float:left;">Choose Media type:
      <select style="display:inline-block;" name="mediatype[Abelson_2834.jpg]">
        <option value="1">marker_icon</option>
        <option value="2">user_image</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="3">general_image</option>
        <option value="4">general_video</option>
        <option value="5">google_static_map</option>
      </select>
      </span> </div="forminputs"></td>
    <td class="start"><button class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> <span>Start</span> </button></td>
    <td class="cancel"><button class="btn btn-warning"> <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i> <span>Cancel</span> </button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="template-upload fade in">
    <td class="preview"><span class="fade in">
      <canvas width="80" height="54"></canvas>
      </span></td>
    <td class="name"><span>Abelson_2852.jpg</span></td>
    <td class="size"><span>3.17 MB</span></td>
    <td><div aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" role="progressbar" class="progress progress-success progress-striped active">
        <div style="width:0%;" class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div="forminputs"> <span style="display:inline-block;float:left;">Choose a pool:
      <select style="display:inline-block;" name="pool[Abelson_2852.jpg]">
        <option selected="selected" value="general_pool">General</option>
        <option value="place">Places</option>
        <option value="geo">Geometrics</option>
        <option value="ads">Advertisment</option>
      </select>
      <span class="pool_place"> <br>
      Choose a pool:
      <select style="display:inline-block;" name="pool_place[Abelson_2852.jpg]">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">place 1</option>
        <option value="2">Places</option>
        <option value="3">Geometrics</option>
        <option value="4">Advertisment</option>
      </select>
      </span> </span> <span style="display:inline-block;float:left;">Choose Media type:
      <select style="display:inline-block;" name="mediatype[Abelson_2852.jpg]">
        <option value="1">marker_icon</option>
        <option value="2">user_image</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="3">general_image</option>
        <option value="4">general_video</option>
        <option value="5">google_static_map</option>
      </select>
      </span> </div="forminputs"></td>
    <td class="start"><button class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> <span>Start</span> </button></td>
    <td class="cancel"><button class="btn btn-warning"> <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i> <span>Cancel</span> </button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="template-upload fade in">
    <td class="preview"><span class="fade in">
      <canvas width="80" height="54"></canvas>
      </span></td>
    <td class="name"><span>Abelson_3160-1.jpg</span></td>
    <td class="size"><span>3.00 MB</span></td>
    <td><div aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" role="progressbar" class="progress progress-success progress-striped active">
        <div style="width:0%;" class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div="forminputs"> <span style="display:inline-block;float:left;">Choose a pool:
      <select style="display:inline-block;" name="pool[Abelson_3160-1.jpg]">
        <option selected="selected" value="general_pool">General</option>
        <option value="place">Places</option>
        <option value="geo">Geometrics</option>
        <option value="ads">Advertisment</option>
      </select>
      <span class="pool_place"> <br>
      Choose a pool:
      <select style="display:inline-block;" name="pool_place[Abelson_3160-1.jpg]">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">place 1</option>
        <option value="2">Places</option>
        <option value="3">Geometrics</option>
        <option value="4">Advertisment</option>
      </select>
      </span> </span> <span style="display:inline-block;float:left;">Choose Media type:
      <select style="display:inline-block;" name="mediatype[Abelson_3160-1.jpg]">
        <option value="1">marker_icon</option>
        <option value="2">user_image</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="3">general_image</option>
        <option value="4">general_video</option>
        <option value="5">google_static_map</option>
      </select>
      </span> </div="forminputs"></td>
    <td class="start"><button class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> <span>Start</span> </button></td>
    <td class="cancel"><button class="btn btn-warning"> <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i> <span>Cancel</span> </button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have tried a few ways to pull out the information but the short of it is that I have to be able to know what the key is so I can test it so I know I'm getting the value.  I don't have a choice on the post data, that is stuck the way it is.  I can't use things like .ToDictionary cause I'm also stuck in .net 2.0.

Here is an attempt at getting the right info via just KeyValuePair thou yes it's wrong but at least I hope it'll give the idea of what is needing to happen.

```
media.file_name = "Abelson_2834.jpg"; // test value to pin to
int type = 3;
// NOTE I KNOW KeyValuePair IS NOT RIGHT.. looking for right way thou
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> obj in Request.Params["mediatype"])
{
    if( obj.Key == media.file_name ){
        type =  int.Parse(obj.Value); 
        // value of type should be 3 since there is a 
        // Request.Params["mediatype"]["Abelson_2834.jpg"] but since you can't call keys
        // by name it thnk it should be an int
        // like Request.Params["mediatype"][0]
    }
}

media.type = ActiveRecordBase<media_types>.Find(type);
ActiveRecordMediator<media_repo>.Save(media);
```

Anyone have an idea on how to make this work?  I would think that turning the String[] to a Dictionary or Hashtable would be the trick but.. as of yet it's not working.

Thank you for the help.
Cheers,
jeremyBass

**SIDE NOTE**
If this was php, I'd just have to go

```
$value = $_POST["mediatype"]["Abelson_2834.jpg"];
```

and I'd have the value needed if that clears things up some.

Comment: I don't get it. `Request.Params["mediatype"]` must be a string since you call `string.IsNullOrEmpty` on it, but then you try to enumerate it as a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Comment: It's not clear what your array contains. A short but complete example with the sample input and expected output would really help.

Comment: `Params` is a `NamedValueCollection` so its a `string` to `string` assciation. You state that value for "mediatype" is an association table. `Request.Params["mediatype"]` must be a `string`. Please provide us with this string. How is it formatted?

Comment: So I edited the question to show the raw post data to show that Request.Params["mediatype"], the param "mediatype" is an array so it's input name would be like name="mediatype[]" except it was set as  name="mediatype[Abelson_2834.jpg]"  .. the goal is that I get the value for one of the items in mediatype[] where the key equals "Abelson_2834.jpg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is this

```
media.file_name = "Abelson_2834.jpg";
int type = 3;
int tmp = int.Parse(Request.Params["mediatype[" + media.file_name+ "]"]);
if(tmp>0){
    type = tmp;
}
```

In short you need to target directly at the first level form keys as C# .net 2.0 at least doesn't understand that an array when coming from a post can have a key other then a int.  When it sees this what it does is treat it as a string so, you call it as one.

Thanks for the help you guys.
Cheers -Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

The input is misleading you.  You actually are getting property[object]=value.  If you create KVPs with Key = some_function(object,property), Value=value you'll be headed in the right direction.  For example, as a one-off of your code above:

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Params["mediatype"])){
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> obj in Request.Params["mediatype"])
        {
           dict_props[obj.Key+"_mediatype"]=value;
           // add each object to a list
        }
 }
 // for each object in the list
 //    for each property
 ...process dictionary....
```